# Leak found: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed

Tags: android, httpclient, speech-recognition

I don't really instantiate an [AndroidHttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html) anywhere in my code, but I do start a recognizer intent, which yields this exception at some point when my application runs:

```
Leak found
java.lang.IllegalStateException: AndroidHttpClient created and never closed
    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.<init>(AndroidHttpClient.java:152)
    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(AndroidHttpClient.java:138)
    at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.SpeechServiceHttpClient.<init>(SpeechServiceHttpClient.java:59)
    at com.google.android.voicesearch.speechservice.ServerConnectorImpl.<init>(ServerConnectorImpl.java:85)
    at com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchContainerImpl.createRecognitionController(VoiceSearchContainerImpl.java:83)
    at com.google.android.voicesearch.GoogleRecognitionService.onCreate(GoogleRecognitionService.java:65)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Assuming the bug is not in Android's code but in mine, this leaked resource could have been created only in one of the following:

1. `SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer()`
2. `new RecognitionListener()`
3. `new Intent(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION)`
4. `SpeechRecognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent)`

But how do I know which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Assuming the bug is not in Android's code but in mine

The leak is in `com.google.android.voicesearch`, which is not your code.

If you can create a small sample project that demonstrates this leak, we can get an issue over to Google and hope that they will address it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you assume it's not in Android? `SpeechRecognizer` and `RecognitionListener` are in ASOP, so you can check (it's not there). Most probably `SpeechServiceHttpClient` uses an `AndroidHttpClient` internally. There is not much you can do but check you are calling all finalizer methods, if any (close(), shutdown(), etc), of the framework classes you are using.

Comment: Thank you Nikolay Elenkov and @CommonsWare .